# Автоматическое исчезновение уведомления js

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток, я хочу автоматически скрывать div через 15 секунд после его появления при помощи fadeOut(), но у меня не получается уловить момент появления этого div'a. Кто-нибудь знает событие или способ сделать это? div генерируется и добавляется в блок с помощью innerHTML.

```js
function notificate(head, text) {

  var icon = 'fa fa-times';
  var iconcolor = '#fff';


  newbox = '<div id="notification"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:' + iconcolor + ';"></i></div><b>' + head + '</b><p>' + text + '</p></div>';

  notifications.innerHTML = notifications.innerHTML + newbox;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#notifications {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 400px;
}
#notification {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #303030;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #222;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.05s;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  cursor: pointer;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
#notification:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
}
#notification .icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #282828;
  float: left;
}
#notification .icon i {
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
#notification p {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 270px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#notification p b {
  margin: 0;
}
#notification b {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="notificate('Заголовок', 'Содержание уведомления');" style="padding:10px;border-radius:5px;background:#fff;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;">Вывести уведомление</div>

<div id="notifications">

</div>
```

Comment: Блок имеет идентификатор?

Comment: как вы добавляете див? приведите ваш код

Comment: Приветствую. Также можно отловить момент добавления div, но для этого надо понимать куда он вставляется.

Comment: @MaximBogdanov я выложил на jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/monoffo/grpbh35y/4/

Comment: @Grundy я выложил на jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/monoffo/grpbh35y/4

Comment: @Dibster, перенес код в сниппет, всю необходимую информацию нужно вставлять непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: @Dibster, вы хотите решение с помощью jQuery?

Comment: у вас сразу ошибка: id - должен быть **уникальным** на странице, а вы вставляете элемент с id="notification" в элемент с id="notification"

Comment: @Dibster, не надо убирать код из вопроса, где **нужен** код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function notificate(head, text) {

  var icon = 'fa fa-times';
  var iconcolor = '#fff';


  newbox = '<div id="notification"><div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:' + iconcolor + ';"></i></div><b>' + head + '</b><p>' + text + '</p></div>';

  notifications.innerHTML = notifications.innerHTML + newbox;

  setTimeout(function () {
    $('div#notification').fadeOut();
  }, 15000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Блок скорее всего должен иметь идентификатор. И если да, твоя задача для одного блока решается так:

**Есть `div`:**

```
<div id="fadeOutBlock">Some text to fadeOut</div>
```

**И код:**

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#fadeOutBlock').fadeOut();
}, 5000)
```

По истечению времени 5 секунд (5000 мс), блок с данным идентификатором скроется.
Вызывать метод `setTimeout` можешь после инициализации (вставки блока) в DOM.

Comment: _но у меня не получается уловить момент появления этого div'a._ - мне кажется вопрос немного о другом

Comment: тогда надо понять как он вставляет элемент в страницу, ведь он должен контролировать этот момент.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

`$( ".yourElement:has(div)" )` - можно сделать таймер, который в цикле будет проверять на наличие элемента.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780822/how-can-i-detect-when-a-new-element-has-been-added-to-the-document-in-jquery

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target, ' элемент был добавлен');
}); // думаю, вместо document можно Ваш элемент поставить, куда div вставляется
```

с помощью http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/

```
$('.yourElement').livequery(function()
{
    console.log(e.target, ' элемент был добавлен');
});
```